# which one in the column is this element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's assume I've got following code:

```
<div id="container">
<div onclick="func(this)"></div>
...
...
<div onclick="func(this)"></div>
</div>
```

On click I need the function `func` to get:
1. the index of the div, where the onclick-event was invoked.
2. the total number of divs in the container.

Comment: 6 downvotes and no mention why? I'm curious what's wrong with this question.

Comment: People cannot parse the English of the two questions, particularly point 1.

Comment: True, it's difficult to tell what's being asked here. I think it's a DOM question (so I added the tag). It's a bit late but since the question is closed but @oneat, maybe you could try clarifying what you are asking. I would've edited the question but I don't want to assume too much.

Comment: I would assume OP wants the index of the div that fired the event, as well as the total number of divs in the container.

Comment: user1689607 got the point. Sorry for my bad english, I will reedit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `func` receives `this` as the first argument, you can simply traverse through the previous siblings, and count how many came before to figure out the index.

And to get the total count, just get the count of `.children` from the parent.

```
function func(elem) {
    var idx = 0;
    var total = elem.parentNode.children.length;
     // --------v----note the assignment!
    while (elem = elem.previousElementSibling) {
        idx++;
    }
    console.log("index:", idx, " of:", total);
}
```

If you need to support older browsers that don't have `.previousElementSibling`, you can use `.previousSibling` and test that the nodeType is 1.

```
function func(elem) {
    var idx = 0;
    var total = elem.parentNode.children.length;
     // --------v----note the assignment!
    while (elem = elem.previousSibling) {
        if (elem.nodeType === 1)
            idx++;
    }
    console.log("index:", idx, " of:", total);
}
```

All of this assumes that there are no other elements in the container that should be counted. If there are others, you'll need to filter them out of the count.

Answer (score 1):

This code will do what you need:

```
function func(el){
    // get the list of all element contained by the parent
    var list = el.parentElement.children, i;
    // get the index of the element
    for (i = 0; i<list.length;i++){
        if (list[i] == el) break;
    }
    // logging index and total childrencount to console (F12)
    console.log("children total: "+list.length);
    console.log("# of element: "+ ++i);
}​
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vmzuM/1)**